# Removing last line break in string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of names (var names) which after running some other code to add or remove names, I want to place in a list called nameupdated:

```
var names = new Array('Alice', 'Bryan', 'Catherine', 'Douglas', 'Emma', 'Frank'); 
var name = "";
var nameupdated = "";
var text = "";

for(var i in names){
name = names[i];
  if (name == "" || name == text || typeof(name) == undefined)
  {

  }
  else{
    nameupdated = nameupdated + name + "\n";
  }
}
```

I can't seem to remove the last line break however I tried to manipulate the code. Anyone with any ideas how?

Comment: i am sure, `join()` function would useful to you `names.join('\n')`

Comment: i don't actually want to join it, the output will be in a form format with the line breaks

Comment: Can you please provide us what is expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic will probably be a lot clearer if you use `.filter` to remove the items you want to exclude, followed by `.join` by newlines. Note that array literals are generally nicer to work with than using the `new Array` constructor:

```js
var text = 'foo';

var names = [
  'Alice',
  'Bryan',
  'Catherine',
  'Douglas',
  'Emma',
  'Frank'
];

var nameUpdated = names
  .filter(name => !(name == "" || name == text || typeof(name) == undefined))
  .join('\n');
console.log(nameUpdated);
```

Comment: I tried with both the ways, still I am not able to figure out what exactly OP is asking, Can you please let me know what OP is trying to achieve, my answer is not as per Op's expectation then I will delete it

Comment: Pretty sure he just doesn't want the a trailing `\n` in the final string. I guess `trim()` would work too

Comment: *I can't seem to remove the last line break however I tried to manipulate the code*, from this sentence what I understood is, he is trying to append `\n` at the end of each element but he want to skip last element of an array

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to do. using trim() did not do the trick.

Comment: @Hannah `.trim` *does* work - `'foo\n'.trim() === 'foo'` (unless names have trailing/leading spaces, which would be quite strange)

Comment: the code didn't run when i tried to use trim. think i'm doing something wrongly in my code because it works if i truncate it down to that function alone, but not when i combine it with other stuff i'm trying to do. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try first If you want to remove last line break then you can do it in one line.
2. Try second if you want string with `new line`

```js
var names = [
  'Alice',
  'Bryan',
  'Catherine',
  'Douglas',
  'Emma',
  'Frank'
];

//Array with \n
var result = [...names].map((d, i) => i < names.length-1 && (name => !(name == "" || name == text || typeof(name) == undefined)) ? d+'\n' : d);

//String with new line after each element

var result1 = [...names].map((d, i) => i < names.length-1 && (name => !(name == "" || name == text || typeof(name) == undefined))? d+'\n' : d).join('');

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
```